# Asus Laptop Battery Health Charging support in Ubuntu

Tags: battery

I have a Asus dual boot laptop with Ubuntu 18.10/Windows 10. In Windows 10 there is an application called Asus Battery Health which allows you to limit the charging the 60 or 80% to improve your battery life. When I have this set to 60% and if I reboot to Ubuntu, it works for some days. But after some restarts/ logouts etc. it just stops working and charges again to 100%. Any idea why?
I don't see any similar option directly in BIOS settings.
I had an old Toshiba laptop where in the same scenario it always works in Ubuntu also once set in Windows.

Comment: Not tested but a solution is given here for Ubuntu 20.04 https://pan.sman.cloud/controlling-the-battery-charging-threshold-on-asus-laptop-with-ubuntu-20-04/ Similar solution here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VxIKFf8I1kg

Answer (score 6):

I have a dual boot laptop Asus (win10 and ubuntu) and I had a similar problem.

After many efforts, I finally found a solution to this problem:
When you turn on your laptop, first boot Windows 10 and run "ASUS cheath charge" and select your battery mode, then restart (** not turn off **) and boot your ubuntu. After this, the battery will remain on the selected level in Windows 10, for example 60% or 80%
Now enjoy your Ubuntu.